# compilation of below statement succeeds why?

Tags: java, scjp

As i know that Object is the super most class of all classes in java. But, below code i am not able to understand. please help me out.

```
Object c = new long[4];
Object d = new int[4];
```

Comment: Actually, i know that int a[] = new int[10]; is possible. how above statements are compiling...

Comment: Because an `array of primitives` is an object.

Comment: @kocko you are right, just want to add that not only of primitives, every array in Java is Object.

Answer (score 7):

> In the Java programming language, arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object (§4.3.2). All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html).

Answer (score 4):

As written, this should give you an error because you are re-declaring a variable named c. However, the following is perfectly valid:

```
Object c = new long[4];
c = new int[4];
```

This works because, as you say, Object is the superclass of all non-primitive types in Java.

Comment: Note; after kocko's edit the redeclaring c issue no longer exists

Answer (score 2):

It compiles because every array in Java is an object, too.

Answer (score 0):

`Object` is the super class of `arrays` in Java (mentioning just arrays because the question demands so).

So when you assign a long array to object it is internally type casted to Object.

Similarly for int. So in the end in both statements the variable on the right is an Object. However, you cannot have `Object c =` in both the lines.

Comment: `Object` is the super class of every class, array, interface and enum in Java, not of "everything in Java". :)

Comment: Yeah. Yeah. I know. Was in a hurry. ;) You can edit. Its difficult to do it from the phone.